# udp socket options for sendng RTP

Tags: sockets, winapi, udp, voip, rtp

I am opening socket on windows platform for sending RTP voice packets. The application is softphone.  What preferable options should be set on this socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need any special options for basic RTP. You can set some of the following options if you're experiencing some problems with your app:

```
SO_SNDBUF
SO_RCVBUF
```

Set the send buffer to your RTP frame size to avoid buffering by the OS. Set the receive buffer to avoid truncated frames if the OS' default buffer size is too small for your frame size.

Other than that I can't really think of anything...